# No video with HTML 5 player in YouTube under Iceweasel

Tags: debian, video, youtube

Today I noticed that I get no video (the audio is there) when watching an YouTube video using the HTML 5 player (enabled on http://youtube.com/html5).

If I use the Flash player, all works correctly, but I'd rather avoid it.

What I have from `gstreamer` installed is:

```
ii  gstreamer0.10-alsa:amd64                     0.10.36-1.1                       amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
ii  gstreamer0.10-gconf:amd64                    0.10.31-3+nmu2                    amd64        GStreamer plugin for getting the sink/source information from GConf
ii  gstreamer0.10-nice:amd64                     0.1.4-1                           amd64        ICE library (GStreamer 0.10 plugin)
ii  gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad:amd64              0.10.23-7.1                       amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "bad" set
ii  gstreamer0.10-plugins-base:amd64             0.10.36-1.1                       amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "base" set
ii  gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:amd64             0.10.31-3+nmu2                    amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "good" set
ii  gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly:amd64             0.10.19-2+b3                      amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "ugly" set
ii  gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio:amd64               0.10.31-3+nmu2                    amd64        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
ii  gstreamer0.10-x:amd64                        0.10.36-1.1                       amd64        GStreamer plugins for X11 and Pango
ii  gstreamer1.0-clutter                         2.0.8-1                           amd64        Clutter PLugin for GStreamer 1.0
ii  gstreamer1.0-libav:amd64                     1:1.2.2-dmo1                      amd64        FFmpeg plugin for GStreamer
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64               1.2.2-1                           amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "bad" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:amd64              1.2.2-1                           amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "base" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64              1.2.1-1                           amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "good" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64              1.2.2-1                           amd64        GStreamer plugins from the "ugly" set
ii  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64                1.2.1-1                           amd64        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
ii  gstreamer1.0-x:amd64                         1.2.2-1                           amd64        GStreamer plugins for X11 and Pango
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0:amd64         0.10.23-7.1                       amd64        GStreamer development files for libraries from the "bad" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0:amd64          1.2.2-1                           amd64        GStreamer development files for libraries from the "bad" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:amd64        0.10.36-1.1                       amd64        GStreamer libraries from the "base" set
ii  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64         1.2.2-1                           amd64        GStreamer libraries from the "base" set
ii  libgstreamer0.10-0:amd64                     0.10.36-1.2                       amd64        Core GStreamer libraries and elements
ii  libgstreamer1.0-0:amd64                      1.2.2-1                           amd64        Core GStreamer libraries and elements
```

Looks like I'm missing a codec, but I don't know which one. I am using Debian "testing", Iceweasel 26.0.  What to do?

Comment: Does [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_js_prop) work? Youtube might only provide the MP4 html5 format, which might not work - see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

Comment: It doesn't work, I don't get any video or sound. I find it odd that HTML5 YouTube worked correctly in Fedora 20 (which I was using before).

Comment: I'm using a fresh install F20 of that now *(still trying to work out whehter to go back to 19 for the Gnome 3.8)*, with Firefox 26, and it works fine. I think as IceWeasel is a fork of Firefox, it might not have this feature, or it might have to be enabled. There is other HTML5 stuff you could test [here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/48-excellent-html5-demos/), then you could find out whether it is the media plugins or html5 support...

Comment: Those HTML 5 stuff works. It's just the videos that don't play, this looks like a codec problem (but I don't know what to install).

Comment: There is other stuff listed [here](https://wiki.debian.org/MultimediaCodecs), apart from that, you may just need to enable it in `about:config` of the browser or something.

Comment: go to the HTML5 labs page to see what you're missing.

Comment: Had the same problem with iceweasel crashing on video playback. I'm complete newbe, set up debian8, monitor frequency was bad for the eyes. This site helped me:
https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo
solved the issue. Now my monitor has optimized frequency, iceweasel doesn't crash anymore, and plays videos with good performance. No flash player needed. May be helpful to others with the same problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to install the `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg` package.

Then, to see if it works, go to http://youtube.com/html5 and see if there's a green tick next to `H.264`.

[edit] On recent Debian versions (>= 8.0) you need gstreamer1.0-libav

Comment: Congrats on getting to 10k!

Comment: I had this issue under Debian Jessie. Uninstalling extra gstreamer1.0 backends while leaving gstreamer1.0-alsa, -libav, -x, -nice, -packagekit, -tools and -plugins-* in place solved the problem for me.